# What is a Scopus indexed conference and how can I identify one?

Tags: conference, scopus

What is meant by a conference indexed in Scopus? It's easy to know which journals are indexed in Scopus from the Scopus homepage. Are there any conferences in Mathematics which are Scopus indexed? Does there exist any page like this https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri where I can identify Scopus-indexed conferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conference indexed in Scopus** does not exist! Rather, it's conference proceedings.

In the *context* of conference and conference proceedings, *mathematics* is as broad as it can be. You might need to narrow down to domains/subdisciplines.

For what you're looking, perhaps [Scimago might have a searchable listing](https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?type=p&area=2600)

**Edit**: PS: just noticed this was asked in 2020!

Answer (score 9):

**There is no such conference.**

Scopus is an indexing database which indexes the publications (journals and conference proceedings). Scopus does not index conferences.

What you are actually asking is: **Whether the conference's proceeding is indexed by Scopus?**

Many conferences publish their proceedings via popular publications such as Springer, IEEE, ACM, Elsevier. If it is a Springer-publishing proceeding: usually, it is LNCS (Lecture Note in Computer Science) and it's sub-lecture notes such as LNAI. Similarly, there is LNEE (electrical engineering), and many such. These LNXX proceedings are indexed in Scopus.

If it is IEEE, usually the papers will appear in IEEE Xplore (which is Scopus-indexed). Similarly for ACM proceedings, ACM Digital Library.

Elsevier publishes under the name of Procedia Technology or Procedia Engineering and few more. These are indexed in Scopus.

There may be other known publishers such as IOS Press, and many more. In that case, you have to check thoroughly where the conference publishes its proceedings and whether that publication is indexed by Scopus.