# Springer proceedings NOT indexed by Scopus

Tags: conference, economics, indexing, proceedings

I am searching for a conference in economics and business. There is **one conference** that looks relatively OK (less probability of being predatory: according to papers which are published in its proceedings; furthemore, past proceedings were indexed by CPCI with 2 years delay). Importantly, the conference is **published as a book by Springer**.

I can either write there a paper or just present just an abstract. The thing is, for a work on paper to be justifiable for me, I need the conference proceedings to be either indexed by CPCI, Science, SS&H, or **proceedings indexed in Scopus**.

Therefore, I have followed [this question on StackExchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/154945/what-is-a-scopus-indexed-conference-and-how-can-i-identify-one) which was relatively optimistic regarding Springer proceedings being indexed in Scopus.

When I tried to search in [Scopus database](https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri) for indexed conference proceedings in Economics and Business, though, I got only 15 results and proceedings from my conference were not among them. Nevertheless, when I searched [Scimagojr](https://www.scimagojr.com) I have found the proceedings on their site.

### The question:

- Is there a possibility of conference proceedings being published by Springer and not indexed by Scopus?
- Does conference proceedings being listed on Scimagojr mean something?
- How many conference proceedings are published by Springer and not indexed in Scopus?
- How can I evaluate with certainty whether conference proceedings are indexed by CPCI, Science, SS&H, or indexed in Scopus?

Comment: *The thing is, for a work on paper to be justifiable for me, I need the conference proceedings to be either indexed by CPCI, Science, SS&H, or proceedings indexed in Scopus.* 
You are in the unlucky positions that this conference is not what you formally need, you are bound to some stupid bureaucracy, go to any conference you deem interesting and discuss with your advisor the funding of the trip. For this trip and for the cheapest possible conference respecting the criteria you need to fullfill...

Comment: What is your goal? attend this conference because it is very interesting and relevant, or just to fullfill the bureaucratic requirements "attend and publish in a xzy conference"?

Comment: I want to think I would like to satisfy both criteria. However, the truth is, attending an interesting conference is just an optional goal now. This conference seems interesting, though, but if it does not meet the criteria I could go there for presentation only (it would not be viable to write a paper as the effort would not have paid out). Otherwise, if it meets them, I would send a whole paper.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now you have 4 questions, when in reality the question is only one, i.e. "How can I be sure that a conference is indexed by CPCI, given that the previous one has been indexed with 2 years delay?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only relevant question you pose is the last one. And the answer is a boring ask "them" (both conference orgnaizers and indexers).

In your specific case:

> furthemore, past proceedings were indexed by CPCI with 2 years delay)

This. Ask whatever CPCI is (and the conference organizers as well) if the conference proceedings will be indexed by CPCI.

If yes, then you have peace of mind (write a paper with them), if no or don't know, then you have peace of mind (of not writing a paper with them).

Comment: Thank you. The first question is also important to me, as I previously thought that Springer guarantees indexation in Scopus, but according to Scopus database itself, this might hold hold only in a limited amount of cases. So I wanted to be sure, whether I did not do something wrong during the search.

Comment: Springer is a big publisher, it does not mean that everything that Springer publishes is indexed by Scopus.
It may be that every *journal* published by Springer is indexed by Scopus, some conference proceedings are published as special issue of a certain journal or of a collection (therefore falling under the umbrella of some journal), and some conference proceedings are published as books and not indexed by S... and you can self-publish basically any book with at least a minimum of academic rigorousness with Springer (as an example: https://www.springer.com/gp/campaign/chemistry-book-2 ) ...